# Best way to learn OOP (php)

Tags: php, oop, object

Where can I find the best way to learn OOP PHP?
I find it difficult to find tutorials beyond the basics and I am looking for something that covers practical usages of OOP in php.

While I acknowledge the question is maybe to broad of a topic, I know there is not a best way to learn something and that i requires practice, but I often search for this specific topic.

When I try to find a good tutorial on OOP I do find the ones that cover most of the basics, but I cannot find a good tutorial about what to do when you know the basics.

Like how do you structure the OOP code and where you can find best practices. That is all I wanted to know.

If my formulation of the question was to shortsighted I apologize for the major inconvenience I have caused in your day to day live, although it was not how I wanted it to be.

Kind regards

Comment: Read out: http://php.net/manual/en/

Comment: How did you learn how to walk or ride a bike or speak?  All of those are harder than OOP.

Comment: check this official documentationhttp://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: Check out the codecademy course on PHP http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-ZQQ64/0/1?curriculum_id=5124ef4c78d510dd89003eb8

Comment: What's possible in terms of OOP best practice has changed significantly in recent years with new versions of PHP (e.g. Scalar Type Hinting in PHP 7). I wrote on e-book on Object-Oriented PHP that's covers how you can use mature OOP practices in modern PHP: https://leanpub.com/object-orientedphp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of learning OOP (PHP specifically) is to get a reasonably short book and read it
slowly and carefully.

I used "PHP Object-Oriented Solutions" by David Powers (Friend of Ed, publishers),
however there are many books out there to choose from (see Amazon.com).

My first introduction to OOP took place in an online Java course, and though I don't use
Java at all, the conceptual framework made PHP OOP easy to learn.

Like any programming, you need to practice, good luck!

Note: The best way is somewhat subjective, so expect a variety of opinions and options,
pick the one that suits your learning style.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I really like the book and will look into JAVA, it might be the best way to wrap my head around this subject!

Answer (score 1):

This book is my favorite:

[Head First PHP & MySQL](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/)

Learning from this book is easy and also funny. There are some nice video tutorials in Lynda.com.

But if you want to learn with practicals, w3school is very useful.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Thank you I did use w3schools already but I will for sure use the book suggestion!